# How to use a KDE screensaver in Gnome?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, kde, screensaver

Really like KDE CLOCK screensaver, but it doesn't even show in Gnome. And a way to get it to work or similar alternatives?

Comment: please add a link to a screenshot of what this screensaver looks like...

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
apt-get install kscreensaver
```

If that doesn't work, take a look at this:
[HOWTO: Replace gnome-screensaver with xscreensaver](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=195557)